# move items from one listbox to another and vice versa

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I had two list boxes named
listbox1 and listbox2

```
 listBox1.DataSource = dt1;
 listBox1.DisplayMember = "EmployeeName";
 listBox1.ValueMember = "EmployeeId";
 listBox2.DataSource = dt2;
 listBox2.DisplayMember = "EmployeeName";
 listBox2.ValueMember = "EmployeeId";
```

now i want to move items from listbox1 to listbox2 and vice versa

I tried but it shows an exception can not change the value when data-source is assigned

The Exception **"Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the datasource of a listbox, the listbox must rely solely on that datasource. you can't change items in the listbox directly, because if you do, there will be discrepancies between the listbox and its datasource. You need to transfer the entries between the datasources, rather than between the listboxes. Basically, you would need to say:

```
 int index = listBox1.SelectedIndex; //Or wherever else you want to get the index from.
 dt2.Add(dt1[index]);
 dt1.RemoveAt(index);

 listBox1.dataSource = null;
 listBox1.dataSource = dt1;

 listBox2.dataSource = null;
 listBox2.dataSource = dt2;
```

It probably isn't wise to use datasources in this case anyway because whenever you transfer something between the two list boxes, the datasources will need to be reset. It's probably wiser to use something like:

```
 foreach(string current in dt1)
      listbox1.Items.Add(current);

 foreach(string current in dt2)
      listbox2.Items.Add(current);
```

And then when you transfer the item, just go:

```
 listbox2.Items.Add(listbox1.Items[index]);
 listbox1.Items.Remove(index);
```

Answer (score -1):

Although I am vaguely guessing here, I suppose the Problem is with your DataSources. If I understand your question right, you want to move entries between Listboxes and not between the DataSources? Through the DataSource you have a linkt to e.g. a table in a database. If you have two different DataSources they might as well be linked to two different tables. Moving Objects between those tables (through your Listboxes) would be a bad idea, wouldn't it?

Maybe try filling the Listboxes via something like DataSource.ToList(); so you release the connection to your tables and when you're done moving your items around write the contents of your Listboxes to the respective DataSources.

I hope that helps a little bit.